# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTestin - Migrating .net 4.7.2 to .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automation

I am in the process of migrating an C# automation solution from .NET4.7.2 to .netCore. I am getting this error and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Issue :
`if(!scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.Resolve<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext>().TestName.Contains("text")) { //code }`

[image]

Error is given on the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext>().TestName

Error : Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TestTools' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it by adding MSTest Nuget packet